# how to insert data into MySQL from xls

Tags: mysql

I am new to Database. I have data in xls sheet and i want to insert that data into a table.
I have only one column data in xls sheet.  The table is in MySQL database. Please help me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Start the MySQL Command Prompt and enter

```
   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ‘C:\\path\\yourfile.csv’ INTO TABLE database.table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘;’ ENCLOSED BY ‘”‘ LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\r\n’ (field1, field2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export it into a .csv file and then upload it: see [this link](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2008/02/import-excel-data-into-mysql-in-5-easy.html)

i believe excel has tools to connect directly with your mysql table as well, perhaps excel has built in tools to export as well?

Answer (score 0):

Or you may want to try the recently released 'MySQL for Excel' module which is part of the 'MySQL Installer' package. It provides native utilities for importing and exporting data to/from MySQL tables right into Excel.

It is located here - http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/